# Java 8 Converting List<Map<String,String> to Map<String,Map<String,String>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert List of Map i.e.

```
List<Map<String,String>
```

to Map Of Map i.e.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>>;
```

In List of Map I am storing Distanace between two Cities.My List of map is :

> [{Destination=IOWA, distance=2000, Source=NY}, {Destination=OHIO,
>   distance=3000, Source=NY}, {Destination=TX, distance=2500, Source=NY},
>   {Destination=NC, distance=1500, Source=TX}, {Destination=NY,
>   distance=2500, Source=TX}, {Destination=DEL, distance=3000,
>   Source=TX}]

Now I have to convert it into

```
MAP<String<Map<String,String>>,
```

so that we can get distance from all city .Outer Map Key will be Source City. Value Map will have Destination City as Key and Distance between Source to Destination as value.  Output will be in format:

> {TX={NC=1500, DEL=3000, NY=2500}, NY={IOWA=2000, TX=2500, OHIO=3000}}

I want to convert it by using Java 8 Stream API. Not sure how to use groupingby.

Comment: Did you give it a shot and tried something out?

Comment: Why not use proper objects? Lists of Maps are always a code smell.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, you're not using the ideal structure for your data. But this should do what you want under the circumstances:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> distancesBySource = distances.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("Source"),
                Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("Destination"), m -> m.get("distance"))));
```

Comment: just be aware that it will throw IllegalStateException if you have a duplicate datapoint

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Mine is receiving upvotes also, so I won't delete it. Is there a "best practice" for such a case?

Comment: @Fildor I think it's acceptable (or at least accepted) to post extended comments as an answer. Personally, I didn't think you added much substance over Kayaman's original comment. But it looks like I'm in the minority on that.